# Change name of "ubuntu" boot entry

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader

I have a multi-boot system with Windows 10 on my main drive and Linux Mint 20 and Ubuntu 20.04 on an external drive. Both Ubuntu and Linux Mint use the same bootloader, which is stored on the ESP on the external drive. This bootloader appears as "ubuntu" in the boot menu of my motherboard, but I would like to change this to something else, like "Linux Mint and Ubuntu". Assuming that this is something both OS's have in common, it can't be changed from the root partition. Instead, it's on the ESP. But how can I customize the boot behaviour from the ESP? Is there any way to change the name of the boot entry?

Some time ago, I managed to change the Windows bootloader name from "Windows Boot Manager" to "Windows 10" using `bcdedit`. But how can I do this with Linux? I have tried using `efibootmgr`, but no succes. I also tried editing `/etc/default/grub` but this didn't work, maybe also because I didn't write the right settings. So how can I change the name of the Linux bootloader in the boot entry? Deleting it in the UEFI settings of the motherboard doesn't work, as it will reappear on every reboot if the external drive is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, but what are the contents of `/etc/default/grub`? The line beginning with `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` should control this entry's value. If you comment out the existing line (add `#` to the beginning of the line) and add a new one below it, it should take effect. For example:

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="My Ubuntu"
```

Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after saving this change.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried editing the /etc/default/grub file in both Ubuntu and Linux Mint, and I ran `sudo update-grub` afterwards, but nothing changed at reboot.

Comment: You may also need to run `grub-install --removable` to update the UEFI entry.

Comment: I finally managed to change the boot entry name. Instead of commenting the existing line out, I just replaced the old value with "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS", which worked just fine. Important to remark is that I immediately deleted the old boot entry in my Firmware settings, creating a new one with "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS", pointing it to `shimx64.efi` after I finished with `/etc/default/grub` in Ubuntu. Maybe this helped it to work, maybe not.